# Simple perl opendir

Tags: linux, perl, perl-module

I am completely new to perl and have just been learning it. I came across this script I need to run that has some network Tstat trace data. However, I get an error 'Cannot parse date.'

The code that generates this is here

```
foreach my $dir (@trace_dirs) {
 undef @traces;
 opendir(DIR, $dir) || die "Can't open dir: $dir \n";
 @traces = grep { /.out$/ && -d "$dir/$_" } readdir(DIR);
 foreach my $trace (@traces) {
  $trace =~ /^(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\w\w\w)_(\d\d\d\d)/;
  $trace_date=&ParseDate("$3/$4/$5 $1:$2") || die "Cannot parse date \n";
  $traces{$trace_date} = $trace;
  $trace_dir{$trace_date} = $dir;
 }
 closedir DIR;
}
```

can some tell me what this code is looking for?

Comment: What are the arguments being passed to ParseDate()? This is a simple debugging problem where you need to analyze your inputs to verify that they are what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 2):

When you run into problems like this, throw yourself a bone by looking at the data you are trying to play with. Make sure that the value in `$trace` is what you expect and that the date string you create is what you expect:

```
 print "Trace is [$trace]\n";
 if( $trace =~ /^(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\w\w\w)_(\d\d\d\d)/ ) {
     my $date = "$3/$4/$5 $1:$2";
     print "date is [$date]\n";
     $trace_date= ParseDate( $date ) || die "Cannot parse date [$date]\n";
     }
```

I'm guessing that the value in `$4`, which apparently is a string like 'Jan', 'Feb', and so on, isn't something that `ParseDate` likes.

Note that you should only use the capture variables after a successful pattern match, lest they be left over from a different match.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I get an error 'Cannot parse date.'

You get the error due to the line:

```
$trace =~ /^(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\w\w\w)_(\d\d\d\d)/;
```

The script expects that all files in the directory with extension `.out` have proper timestamps in the beginning of their names. And the line of the script lack any error handling.

Try adding some check here, e.g.:

```
unless($trace =~ /^(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\w\w\w)_(\d\d\d\d)/) {
   warn "WRN: Malformed file name: $trace\n";
   next;
}
```

That checks if the file name matches, and if it doesn't, warning would be printed and it would be skipped.

Alternatively you can also add the check to the `grep {} readdir()` line:

```
@traces = grep { /.out$/ && /^(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\d\d)_(\w\w\w)_(\d\d\d\d)/ && -d "$dir/$_" } readdir(DIR);
```

to filter out misplaced `.out` files (hm, actually directories) before they reach the loop which calls the `ParseDate` function.